# How to mock a date object using Jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, date, mocking, jestjs

I am working on a test case where I need to compare date fields (**creation_time** and **last_attempt_time**) in an expect block. Sometimes it fails due to millisecond value in a date changes. So I need to mock a date object which should return specified date and it should be utilized for all the test case modules wherever Date object is used in a test case in a project.

```
// sample.test.ts

it('should return an reset object', () => {

    // Preparing
    const updatedChangeRequest: any = {
        creation_time: new Date(),
        attempts: 0,
        last_attempt_time: new Date()
    };

    // Executing
    const result = ClassName.methodName();

    // Verifying
    expect(result).toEqual(updatedChangeRequest);
});
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here. For example, you can reassign the whole **Date** object and replace it with a mock implementation or override individual methods (and then restore them after your test case is run). But there's already [a module called `mockdate` in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate) for that.

Using mockdate, you can do:

```
const MockDate = require('mockdate');

it('should return an reset object', () => {       
    MockDate.set(Date.now()); // sets now to Date.now()

    // Preparing
    const updatedChangeRequest: any = {
        creation_time: new Date(),
        attempts: 0,
        last_attempt_time: new Date()
    };
    // Executing
    const result = ClassName.methodName();
    // Verifying
    expect(result).toEqual(updatedChangeRequest);

    MockDate.reset();
});
```

To mock the **Date** in all test files, you can set [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array) in your jest config file:

```
// jest.config.js
{
  // ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "./mockdate.js"
  ]
}

// mockdate.js
const MockDate = require('mockdate');

beforeAll(() => {
  MockDate.set(Date.now());
});

afterAll(() => {
  MockDate.reset();
});
```

To confirm that it works, you can run the following test:

```
// mockdate.test.js

test('It Should always return the same value for Date.now()', async () => {
  const before = Date.now();
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  const after = Date.now();
  expect(before).toEqual(after);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. but i have 15 test case files. if i follow this i have to use beforeAll and afterAll for all the test suits in all modules. Is there any way to put this as a common file like manual mocks? and avoid declaring on each modules.

Comment: Thats works perfect, Thanks! Is there any way to achieve this in jest without using 3rd party packages such as mockdate and momentJS?

Comment: Mockdate's repository is hosted on GitHub and the main script contains around 80 lines of code. You can read the code and borrow the parts you need.

Comment: Hey i tried this block of code, but endup in the error  stating **TypeError: Date.now is not a function**

```        const mockDate: any = new Date(1466424490000)
        const spydate= jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => mockDate)

```